# Electron app only works on computers where it was builded

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

I'm trying to create electron app for MacOS. To do this, i'm using macos catalina on virtual box. I can tried dmg file using electron-builder and forge. It works fine for me, i can install and ru application. But it doesn't work on other PC's. People can run dmg and install, but can't run it, "The application app_name can't be opened".
forge config:

```
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {},
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
  name: '@electron-forge/maker-dmg',
  config: {
    format: 'ULFO'
  }
}
  ],
};
```

Builder config:

```
"build": {
    "files": [
      "**/*",
      "!node_modules/"
    ],
    "appId": "lib",
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ]
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "uninstallDisplayName": "Remove Library",
      "shortcutName": "Library",
      "menuCategory": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "license": "license.md",
      "language": "0x046D",
      "multiLanguageInstaller": true,
      "unicode": true,
      "installerIcon": "icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "icon.ico"
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg",
      "icon": "icon.ico",
      "asarUnpack": "**/*.node",
      "arch": [
 "universal"
       ]
    },
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": "license.md",
        "to": "license.md",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      "./src/extraResources/**",
      {
        "from": "tor",
        "to": "tor",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

It doesn't work event with a clear application which just opens window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign the application so it can be able to be run on other peoples machines.

Comment: We tried to build on apple machine, it still works only on it.

Comment: You need to do notarization of the app on the apple machine. https://www.electron.build/code-signing